# How to count number of files groupped by date in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, count, hdfs

How could we count files from a hdfs folder, groupped by date?

```
Example:
2020-01-03 10:00:00 - file 1
2020-01-03 11:00:00 - file 2
2020-01-03 12:00:00 - file 3
2020-02-03 10:00:00 - file 4

Expected result:
3 2020-01-03
1 2020-02-03
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the below command. The `stat "%y"` command helps you get the modification date and `cut -d' ' -f1|sort|uniq -c` will cut the date, sort it and count the unique values.

```
hdfs dfs -stat "%y" path | cut -d' ' -f1|sort|uniq -c
```